# HTTP Get and write to network share much slower than writing to local drive

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, network-share

I have a `C# app` that is migrating data from a `website` to our clients new system. To get the files from the existing system, we are using `HttpWebRequest`, once we've got the response it is written to disk and we move on to the next file. Pretty straight forward. The throughput we have to average is ~140Mbit per sec. Using multiple threads (8 to 12), and a 5 to 7 instances of the process, I'm able to get hit the target throughput, but only if I'm writing to a local disk. If I change it to write to the `NAS drive`, throughput drops by at least half.

I've tried writing to different NAS devices, and also tested on different machines with similar results.

I've tried running the app on multiple machines writing to the same NAS, and that does help, but I'm up to three machines, and still have not matched my single machine, write to Local disk performance.

I have not tried running with two NICs yet (they are setting up a test environment for me to try this after Christmas). That is the only thing that I can think of that might help, though I'm baffled as the NIC on all of the machines are gigabit, so I would not have though I was maxing it out.

This is a windows environment. "Windows 7, Windows server 2008."

Are there any registry settings that could help? I've looked into [NetworkThrottlingIndex](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasp/thread/4f275ed8-fa95-49b2-ac0f-0902b82a5013/), but that seems to only apply to incoming data, and only when a multimedia app is also running (Media player, IE, etc)

Comment: Great question ToddK and welcome to SO, just a suggestion your question might be better suitable for ServerFault.

Comment: There's some inherent added latency in communication over a network.  Keep in mind that the request must be received and interpreted, and data must be sent.  All this according to the protocol you use, which was probably designed for much more complex things than this -- meaning there's probably a bunch of stuff happening that doesn't need to.  Plus the other side still has to read from its local drive...

Comment: What is "the NAS drive" for kind of NAS? Can you write faster than at most half of 140 Mbit using some other transfer method (SMB, FTP) or while transferring from another computer?

Comment: Thanks all, now that I'm testing on our soon to be production equipment, which have two nics (public and private), I'm able to max out our incoming throughput at the office.  @Surjit, I was concerned that it was a coding issue, luckly it wasn't. I will remember ServerFault from now on.